# Difficulty Iterating through Dictionary to Search .txt for Values in Dictionary

Tags: python, openpyxl

The goal for my code is to convert an excel spreadsheet into a Dictionary + use that Dictionary to search a .txt file for a string + print out counts for the # of times each string was used in text. What I'm having trouble with is iterating through the Dictionary and getting counts for all Dictionary values.

I've tried to enumerate and iterate through the values using for loops, but I still end up getting counts for "Carla" only instead of getting counts for all Dictionary items.

```
Dict = {}
for row in range(1, dictionary.max_row+1):
    for col in range(1, 2):
         cell_value = dictionary.cell(row=row, column=col).value
         Dict[cell_value] = dictionary.cell(row=row, column=1).value

def searchtxt():
     count = 0
     with open('26440384.txt', 'r') as f:
        for key in Dict.values():
            print(key)
            for line in f:
                count += line.count(str(key))
                print(count)
                count = 0
searchtxt()
```

RETURNS:

```
Carla
6
God
radiation
```

I get the code to print out all items of the dictionary, but it only counts the number of times "Carla" is present in the text. I want the code to return this:

```
Carla
6
God
4
radiation
3
```

**s/p Klaas' Edits**:

```
def searchtxt():
    count = 0
    with open('26440384.txt', 'r') as f:
        for key in Dict.values():
            print(key)
            lineList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('26440384.txt', 'r')]
            for key in lineList:
                count += lineList.count(str(key))
                print(count)
            count = 0
searchtxt()
```

RETURNS:

```
Carla
1
God
1
radiation
1
```

SOLUTION:

```
def searchtxt():
    count = 0
    with open('26440384.txt', 'r') as f:
        for key in Dict.values():
            print(key)
            for line in f:
                count += line.count(str(key))
                print(count)
                count = 0
            f.seek(0)
searchtxt()
```

Comment: `collections.Counter` is your friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you're reading the file once and then your pointer is at the end of the file, so next time you come to the section

```
for line in f:
            count += line.count(str(key))
            print(count)
            count = 0
```

there are no more lines in the file to read as you're already at the end.
If the file isn't too big (or you're not worried about memory) I would read the file into a list first and then loop through that list

```
lineList = [line. rstrip('\n') for line in open(fileName)]
```

So rather than for line in f you would go for line in lineList: etc

Comment: Thanks Klaas. Tried your code and I was able to get counts after each dictionary value (progress!) but the count was 1 for all entries . Any ideas why that might be the case? Thanks again in advance. I should have clarified that I'm new to python.

Comment: looksl ike an indent problem
`for line in f:
                count += line.count(str(key))
                print(count)
                count = 0`
your print(count) and count = 0 should go at the same level as where you start the for loop (i.e. one level of indent back)

Comment: Hmm I tried tinkering around with indentation. I don't think I see what you're seeing. I posted a revised code to the main post. Can you take a look?

Comment: I figured it out. What you wrote about the pointer being in the "end" position seemed like the root of the problem so I used seek() to set the pointer to 0 at the end of my loop. Thanks again for all the help!